# Webview Opening Browser even with override

Tags: java, android, webview

I implemented a webview into my parse notification app, but when the webview opens it opens a browser.  I then added the "shouldoverrideURL" but still the same problem exists, any one have any ideas.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thankyou

```
 import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.ParsePush;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.PushService;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button push;

    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {         
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onReceive invoked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);

        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.homedepot.com");

        push = (Button)findViewById(R.id.senPushB);
        push.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return(true);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(MyCustomReceiver.intentAction));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        JSONObject obj;
        try {
            obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("alert", "hello!");
            obj.put("action", MyCustomReceiver.intentAction);
            obj.put("customdata","My message");

            ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
            ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();

            // Push the notification to Android users
            query.whereEqualTo("deviceType", "android");
            push.setQuery(query);
            push.setData(obj);
            push.sendInBackground(); 
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
http://m.homedepot.com
```

I am using this code to open the url in browser:

```
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.loadUrl("http://m.homedepot.com");
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return(true);
    }
    }
);
```

Comment: Still getting the same result whether its the mobile site or another site

Comment: @user3749843 Asking to open browser?

Comment: It doesn't ask it will open the main activity page but then it will open the browser with the URL

Comment: @user3749843 Wait it is asking for opening browser after loading. There must be some other problem.

Comment: @user3749843 Where are you using Callback object?

Comment: could it have to do with the Callback?  Android Studio is saying that the private inner class is never used.  And its shaded grey

Comment: @user3749843 You are not using it anywhere.

Comment: still trying to implement

Comment: @user3749843 Ok, I forgot to add two braces. I added now, so use the latest answer.